# How can I update ListView when my data source changes?

Tags: wpf, listview

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=108085

In that video, when I changes data source by add more data the list view doesn't update? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (or any collection that implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), really) as the data source for the `ListView`. This way any changes made to the collection will be reflected in the `ListView`.